# Postgres sql count number of days active in month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like so:

```
meterId | startDate  | endDate  |location
meter01 | 2017-05-01 |2017-05-16| locA
meter02 | 2017-05-01 |9999-12-31| locB
meter03 | 2017-01-01 |9999-12-31| locA
meter04 | 2017-01-01 |9999-12-31| locB
```

I need to return a count for how many days a location had activity for in a given month.  The query would need to return this:
(Given there is 31 days in May)

```
location |  Month  |  days  | 
locA     |  May-17 |    47  |
locB     |  May-17 |    62  |
```

what i have tried so far is something like this: (note i am joining to another table which isn't optimum and shown here)

```
SELECT count(distinct(read_date)) AS days, location from t where EXTRACT(MONTH FROM read_date) = 5 and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM read_date) = 2017
```

It's somewhat close.  It has duplicates of location however.  I also need the date in the format as above.

New edit for @StanislavL

```
    select SUM(sub.intervalEnd - sub.intervalStart +1) as days,
     location
from (select 
    location,
    case when effective_start_date> '2017-05-01' then effective_start_date else '2017-05-01' end as intervalStart,
    case when effective_end_date< '2017-05-31' then effective_end_date else '2017-05-31' end as intervalEnd
from my_table

where (effective_start_date<='2017-05-01' and effective_end_date>='2017-05-01')
   OR (effective_start_date<='2017-05-31' and effective_end_date>='2017-05-31'))sub
  group by location
```

Comment: From where you got the count 47 for locA for may-17? From your data the count doesn't look proper.

Comment: @Sumit, 16 + 31 = 47

Comment: @Sumit
yeah the first meter is only active for 16 days whereas the rest are active for the whole month.

Comment: Where is read date in the table?

Comment: I have modified your query a litte bit, please try this one. SELECT count(distinct(read_date)) AS days, to_char(read_date, 'Month')||'-'|| to_char(read_date,'YY')as Month,  location from t where EXTRACT(MONTH FROM read_date) = 5 and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM read_date) = 2017 GROUP BY Location, read_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should introduce first a select to retrieve desired intervals.

```
select 
    location,
    case when startDate> :monthBegin then startDate else :monthBegin end as intervalStart,
    case when endDate< :monthEnd then endDate else :monthEnd end as intervalEnd,
from the_table t
where (startDate<=:monthBegin and endDate>:monthBegin)
   OR (startDate<:monthEnd and endDate>=:monthEnd)
```

where `monthBegin=01.05.2017` and `monthEnd=31.05.2015`

Then place the select in the FROM section of another one

```
select SUM(sub.intervalEnd - sub.intervalStart) as days,
       sub.location
from (subselect) sub
```

where you need to sum interval differences

Comment: Hi Stan,
I have tried your query and it runs but gives no results.  Can you please check what I have done.  I have added it to the bottom of my original question.  Thanks

Comment: remove group by from inner query - sub the `group by location, effective_start_date, effective_end_date`/ Ideally create SQL fiddle. It's hard to tell what is wrong blindly. First execute the inner query to be sure it returns desired intervals/

Comment: also in some cases you `''` and `'` in the `case when`. Why?

Comment: I think I have the query working now.  However, I had to add a +1 at the top for some reason to get the correct amount - presumably your suggestion counted days between excluding or something.  I'm just wondering if there are any implications on doing this e.g. it could pull a null value into the table or something?  I have edited the query in my question to show.  But otherwise seems to be working...

Comment: I think `+1` is correct. If we subtract `2017-05-01` from `2017-05-01` the result is 0 but in your case it should be 1. I think the final result query is fine. Accept the answer as correct if it works.

Comment: Thanks @StanislavL very grateful for your help, Seems to be perfect. Daryn

Comment: Would you happen to know how to add the date (MM/YYYY)  to each returned row?  Can't figure out how to do it. ..

Comment: EXTRACT (field FROM source) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT e.g. `EXTRACT(MONTH from startDate)`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, this is the final working example

```
select location,  subItem1, item2, SUM(sub.intervalEnd - sub.intervalStart +1) as days

from (select 
    location, item1,item2,
    case when effective_start_date> '2017-05-01' then effective_start_date else '2017-05-01' end as intervalStart,
    case when effective_end_date< '2017-05-31' then effective_end_date else '2017-05-31' end as intervalEnd,
    case when item1 =  'APPLE' then item1 else 'ORANGE' end as subItem1
from myTable

where (effective_start_date<='2017-05-01' and effective_end_date>='2017-05-01')
   OR (effective_start_date<='2017-05-31' and effective_end_date>='2017-05-31')
group by item1, item2, location, effective_start_date, effective_end_date
   )sub
  group by location, subItem1, item2
```

There are some extra fields and a 'case' query in there (item1, item2) for my own needs which may serve to help.